# How to retrieve the product variant ID that a specific discount code applies to

Tags: graphql, shopify, variant, discount

How can I retrieve the product variant ID that a specific discount code applies to using Shopify GraphQL?

This is my GraphQL query

```
  const query = `query codeDiscountNodeByCode($code: String!) {
        codeDiscountNodeByCode(code: $code) {
          id
          codeDiscount {
            ... on DiscountCodeBasic {
              status
              customerGets {       
                  items       
              }
              combinesWith {
                productDiscounts
              }
              minimumRequirement {
                __typename
                ... on DiscountMinimumQuantity {
                  greaterThanOrEqualToQuantity
                }
              }
              title            
              shortSummary
              summary
              discountClass
              customerSelection {
              __typename  
              }
            }
          }  
        }
      }`
```